# Trying to use custom element, "You tried to use polymer without loading it first", it's definitely imported

Tags: jquery, html, polymer

I've been trying to use a custom element for a paper-dialog popup that I want to use. If I set up a test page within the file the custom element is defined in, using all the same imports as my index, it works. If I import the custom element into any other page, it no longer works. Even if I load the test file that does work into a div on another page, it gives me the error `Uncaught Error: You tried to use polymer without loading it first. To load polymer, <link rel="import" href="components/polymer/polymer.html">`

I definitely have the `polymer.html` import in my custom element file. Even if I take the custom element and define it in my index, exactly the same code from the external test, it returns this error. I don't understand why and I've searched extensively. Does anyone know why?

Here's the code for my custom element:

```
    <polymer-element name="share-dialog" attributes="pageid, post">
<template>
    <paper-dialog backdrop autoCloseDisabled id="overlay" transition="paper-dialog-transition-bottom" heading="Share">
        Long-press, highlight and copy: <br>
        <center><paper-input id='share_box'type='text' name='share' value='xxxxx/index.php?page=news&id={{pageid}}&post={{post}}'></paper-input></center><br>
        <center>
            <paper-button core-overlay-toggle raised>Close</paper-button>
        </center>
    </paper-dialog>
</template>
<script>

Polymer('share-dialog', {
    toggle: function() {
        this.$.overlay.toggle();
    }
});

</script>
</polymer-element>
```

Obviously I use an actual url in that input box, just for the sake of privacy I've edited that out.

These are my imports:

```
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.js">

<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-icons/core-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-icons/social-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-spinner/paper-spinner.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-animated-pages/core-animated-pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-animated-pages/transitions/slide-from-right.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-menu/core-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-drawer-panel/core-drawer-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-item/core-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-style/core-style.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/font-roboto/roboto.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-checkbox/paper-checkbox.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-fab/paper-fab.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-toast/paper-toast.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-progress/paper-progress.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-transition/core-transition.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog-transition.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog-base.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-elements/paper-elements.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-overlay/core-overlay.html">
```

No error is thrown until I try to call `<share-dialog></share dialog>`

Answer (score 5):

You're including `polymer.js` and `polymer.html`. You should only include `polymer.html`.

Comment: Oh wow, of all the people to get an answer from I did not expect it to be the person I learned the most from about polymer in the first place.

However, I have since removed `polymer.js` imports and am still experiencing issues when attempting to use my custom element on any page other than the page it's defined on standalone. Or rather, if I import it into any page, it throws `TypeError: undefined is not a function` after loading that page into my main content div using jquery.

Premature send, had to edit in the rest.

Comment: @ZackCampbell Check chrome network tab see if you have any 404 for imports

Comment: @Ahmadreza No, I'm not getting any 404s on imports, whether I import them locally or directly from polymer-project.org

Answer (score 1):

Sounds strange. When I made a plunker using your above example it works -

http://plnkr.co/edit/Gd84hbHTct9ht94acC1N?p=preview

The only reference I had to include that isn't in your code above was  in the index.html page

I also removed a reference to polymer.js which isn't needed here

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="share-dialog.html">
</head>

<body>

  <share-dialog id="myDialog"></share-dialog>
  <button onclick="showDialog()">Show</button>

  <script>
    function showDialog() {
      document.getElementById("myDialog").toggle();
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

share-dialog.html

```
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-icons/core-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-icons/social-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-spinner/paper-spinner.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-animated-pages/core-animated-pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-animated-pages/transitions/slide-from-right.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-menu/core-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-drawer-panel/core-drawer-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-item/core-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-style/core-style.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/font-roboto/roboto.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-checkbox/paper-checkbox.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-fab/paper-fab.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-toast/paper-toast.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-progress/paper-progress.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-transition/core-transition.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog-transition.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog-base.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-elements/paper-elements.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-overlay/core-overlay.html">

<polymer-element name="share-dialog" attributes="pageid, post">
  <template>
    <paper-dialog backdrop autoCloseDisabled id="overlay" transition="paper-dialog-transition-bottom" heading="Share">
      Long-press, highlight and copy:
      <br>
      <center>
        <paper-input id='share_box' type='text' name='share' value='xxxxx/index.php?page=news&id={{pageid}}&post={{post}}'></paper-input>
      </center>
      <br>
      <center>
        <paper-button core-overlay-toggle raised>Close</paper-button>
      </center>
    </paper-dialog>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('share-dialog', {
      toggle: function() {
        this.$.overlay.toggle();
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Accidentally deleted my comment intending to edit, ugh mobile. The only difference I can see between our scripts is you are using a button to call `toggle` and I have been using divs with click events, but divs with click events works in my test script, it just gives me that error when I try to import my custom element. I'm on my phone about to head to bed now, so I'll report back if I manage to glean anything from this. Thank you for your input and effort.

Comment: So it seems I can get it working on my posts page independently, but when I load it into the content div of my index, it stops working. It keeps giving me `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` from polymer.js, which I am no longer importing per your suggestion. This is how it was for me before as well. I was able to get it working in a test example, but when I tried to load it into my primary content it stopped working.

Comment: Can you upload your project to GitHub? It's a little tricky to know what's going wrong without seeing how you're using the element.

Comment: @robdodson Sidenote: all of the problems I'm having could probably be circumvented if you could inform me of another way to show paper-dialogs. I've been trying for awhile and this method that is not working as a custom element when imported is the only one I've used so far that kind of works.

Comment: Hi Guys, any update on this. I'm experiencing a similar issue.