# Basic test of Polymer throws a "You tried to use polymer without loading it first" error

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, polymer

I'm trying to "see if it works" with a simple polymer app. I've built my custom element according to the [guidelines](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/platform/custom-elements.html) (with the addition of a noscript attribute on the element). But, my element is not rendering. When I load `index.html`, I just get an empty browser window.

My project:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="lorem-element.html">
  <title>my-app</title>
</head>
<body unresolved>
<lorem-element></lorem-element>
</body>
</html>
```

lorem-element.html

```
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="lorem-element" noscript>
  <template>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, dollars cents and such...</p>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

When I request `index.html`, I see my web server receive requests for

- index.html
- webcomponents.min.js
- lorem-element.html

I see the responses go out from the web server and I see them received in the network tab of Chrome Dev Tools.

I do *not* see any requests for polymer.html, which I think is odd.

When I go to Chrome's console to invoke Polymer.waitingFor(), I get the error
`Polymer.waitingFor is not a function`

Calling Polymer() returns `You tried to use polymer without loading it first. To load polymer, ...`, etc.

I'm stuck on this, and I've searched [here](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/502) and read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27890439/trying-to-use-custom-element-you-tried-to-use-polymer-without-loading-it-first) with no luck, either.

My Chrome is up to date, at 42.0.2311.152.

Can anybody see what I've missed? Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I was trying to run the page on the go without a web server.

From [this](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/start/creatingelements.html) page:
*You must run your app from a web server for the HTML Imports to work properly. They cannot be loaded from file:// due to the browser’s security restrictions.*

Something like [polyserve](https://github.com/polymerlabs/polyserve) might help you.

Comment: My post mentions that I am running a web server. I can try different web servers, though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The element should not include the web components polyfill. Running the polyfills twice will break, so you should **only** include the polyfill once, in your top-level document.

You really should be seeing some kind of more useful error, and I'm not sure why you're not. But removing the first script tag from the element will fix your problems:

```
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="lorem-element" noscript>
  <template>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, dollars cents and such...</p>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

Live version here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/QsnK8sxvEweZGreK560x?p=preview

Comment: Interesting. I removed the web components polyfill from the element and it still didn't work. I moved the project to another web server and it did work.

The one that worked was a standard Linux box, running Apache. At my place of work, we actually roll our own web server. So, I'm guessing maybe it doesn't properly support HTML imports. Thanks!